# Access model attributes inside DisplayTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a DisplayTemplate for `DateTime` properties.

For example I have the following Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? TimeFrom { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? TimeUntil { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```

in my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)       // Expected output: 13.11.2015
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TimeFrom)   // Expected output: 08:00
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TimeUntil)  // Expected output: 12:00
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeDate)   // Expected output: 15.11.2015 08:55
```

In my DisplayTemplate I have the following code:

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Reflection
@model DateTime?
@{
    var type = Model.GetType();
    var attribute = type.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (DataTypeAttribute)) as DataTypeAttribute;

}
@if (Model != null)
{
    if (attribute != null)
    {
        if (attribute.DataType == DataType.Date)
        {
            @Model.Value.ToShortDateString()
        }
        if (attribute.DataType == DataType.Time)
        {
            @Model.Value.ToShortTimeString()
        }
        else
        {
            @Model.Value
        }
    }
    else
    {
        @Model.Value
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there's never a `DataTypeAttribute` found.
The only CustomAttributes found are `Serializable` and `__DynamicallyInvokable`-Attributes.

In the model we always have a DataType attribute for `DateTimes`.
How do I find the current `DataTypeAttribute`?

Comment: I believe you would need to type your template to `MyModel`. The BCL Nullable<T> type would have no knowledge of your annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are searching through the attributes assigned to the `DateTime?` type itself, not to the property of the `MyModel` class. No wander this data model attribute is not found in these.

All built in data model attributes populate `ViewData.ModelMetadata` object, so you should be able to access the name of the data type with this:

```
ViewData.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName
```

Unfortunately this is a string for some reason, so you will probably need to compare it to something like `DataType.Date.ToString()`.

More information on other model metadata properties can be found in [ModelMetadata class description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try DisplayFormat?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775220/ASP-Net-MVC-What-are-the-uses-of-Display-DisplayNa

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}")]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? TimeFrom { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}")]
    public DateTime? TimeUntil { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```